# Voltage regulator 78M05 supply line reverse biased Zener diodes

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, voltage-regulator, zener

I have a technics graphic equalizer SH-D5000 and it keeps on frying reverse biased Zener diodes which are in series with the input of a 5 volt regulator. The supply line is 40 volts DC. What Zener diodes can I use?

Comment: That's a somewhat worrying design. A linear regulator to step down 40 V to 5 V? There'd better be next to no load on that 5 V rail.

Comment: Two reverse biased zener diodes are used to feed the regulator. Help choose the correct zener diodes for such a circuit

Comment: What is the voltage and power rating of the Zener diodes you are currently using, and what current does the 7805 have to supply?

Comment: The 7805 has to supply about 1Amp but for the original zeners have no readable prints. I had replaed them with 12 v zeners.

Comment: My immediate reaction would be to skip the zener diodes on the input, and replace the 7805 with an SMPS. For example, this: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/445/173010542-1715890.pdf is a pin-compatible 7805 replacement with drastically higher efficiency that will accept 40V input directly (but there are quite a few others as well).

Comment: @DavidLunda 12 V at 1 A is 12 W, *far* more than most diodes can handle. You need to get a zener diode rated for the power it's going to dissipate. Or even better, do Jerry's idea.

Comment: Something seems off here. If the 5V regulator only needs to supply 1A then that's a 5W requirement. If that 1A originates from a 40V supply then the zener + regulator need to dissipate 35W of heat. I'm doubtful the fine engineers at Technics would have designed such a system.

Comment: If you're correct that 40V feeds a 5V linear regulator via series zeners, then it has to be that it is a low current supply, far less than 1A. It's likely the regulator is spec'ed as a "1A" regulator but that's just a max spec. That actual current draw depends on the circuit attached to it. Does the regulator mount to a heat sink? That will provide a clue on how much current the designers anticipated. If there's no heat sink then it's probably designed to draw <200mA. Also, how (physically) big are the zeners that blew? This will provide another clue as to how much current is expected.

Comment: The original zeners are small in size and there is no heat sink on the regulator. I wish I could easily access to the device Jerry has recommende

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the circuit truly is a 40V supply into back-to-back Zeners into a linear 5V regulator, and the Zeners are physically small and the regulator has no heatsink, we have enough information to choose an appropriate Zener voltage.

First, note the linear regulator has a min and max input voltage spec. If it’s a 7805 or similar that would be 8V to 25V.

That means the Zeners have to at least knock the 40V down to 25V and preferably lower, so your 12V Zeners are not sufficient: you’d need at least a 15V Zener to bring the regulator input below 25V.

The regulator likely has better heat dissipation properties than the Zener so we’d want to force as much of the heat to the regulator. That means run it at its highest input voltage and minimizing the Zener voltage.

A 15V Zener is the theoretical minimum, so a good choice may be an 18V Zener. Choosing a 1W package gives us the most current capacity. How much current? An 18V 1W Zener is comfortable up to only about 15mA: about a quarter Watt. The regulator similarly dissipates about a quarter Watt, as it has 17V across it (40 – 18  – 5).

An appropriate part would be an 18V 1Watt Zener, for example 1N4746A.